# Should a router reply Multicast Listener Discovery (MLD) General Query?

Tags: ipv6, multicast

I am working on a Linux (CentOS) installation working as bridge, there is an IPv6 router on one side, and client machines on other side, it appears that the router does not reply Multicast Listener Discovery (MLD) General Query, and becasue of 'multicast_snooping' mechanism, following multicast packets are not forwarded to the router, therefore result in problems.

I have had a check with RFC 2710 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2710), and not able to figure out 'Should a router reply Multicast Listener Discovery (MLD) General Query?', looks like the RFC does not specify this behavior.

1. Can somebody help to tell me (or point me where I can get the info) 'Should a router reply Multicast Listener Discovery (MLD) General Query?'
2. If the behavior is really not specified, what does most routers do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "_Should a router reply Multicast Listener Discovery (MLD) General Query?_" Only if the router is configured for multicast routing, which is very different from unicast routing. Unicast has a single destination, and unicast routers know how to deliver to the destination, but multicast has no single destination, so multicast routing is designed to prevent multicast from going where it has not been requested.

Comment: Thanks, in my case, the router is an IPv6 router, which is responsible for distributing IPv6 network address (SLAAC), so, it should reply MLD General Query?